# Show posts from custom post type on homepage in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

So I registered a custom post type called 'books' in Wordpress, and it works fine. I added a few books in admin using that custom post type, and what I'm trying to do now is one of these two:

- show, for example, 5 last posts I added to 'books' custom post type, on a homepage
- show 5 posts I added to 'books' custom post type, on a homepage, by calling their ID-s

I'm great with frontend development, and I know Wordpress codex very well, so I'm pretty good with Wordpress advanced stuff, but I'm not the greatest with PHP functions, so I always find hard time searching for correct function to use for some special task. So I can probably do this if someone give me a function name or point me to the right page of the Wordpress Codex, on Wordpress site.

Can anyone point me to the right direction or give me a sample code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, and belongs on the WordPress stack exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) with following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Books
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">

<?php
//post type should be books
//posts_per_page indicates how many posts you want to show
$type = 'books';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Afterwards create a page using this page template and set it as homepage.

Comment: -1 for using `caller_get_posts`. It is really been long time depreciated. You should know by now it's been replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

Comment: Tnx for the update. I've edited the code